# Using jquery Ajax in Laravel 4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I am newbie to ajax jquery and trying to understand the code and trying to implement it. I would let you know what exactly i want to do and what i am doing.

I have a search box where i input the "sku" and i get the tables and the information of that particular sku.

I have this in my **routes.php**

```
Route::get('bestsellers', array('as'=>'bestsellers', 'uses' =>'SalesFlatOrderItemsController@index'));
```

In my controllers i have

```
class SalesFlatOrderItemsController extends \BaseController {
$sku_query = Input::get('sku');

        if($sku_query){
        $orders = SalesFlatOrder::join('sales_flat_order_item as i','sales_flat_order.entity_id','=','i.order_id')
                         ->select((array(DB::Raw('DATE(i.created_at) as days'), DB::Raw('sum(i.qty_ordered) AS qty_ordered'), DB::Raw('sum(i.row_total) AS row_total'),'i.item_id', 'i.name','i.sku')))
                         ->where('i.sku','=',$sku_query)
                         ->groupBy('i.sku')
                         ->orderBy('qty_ordered','Desc')
                         ->paginate(10);

    }

    return View::make('sales_flat_order_items.bestsellers')->with('orders', $orders);
}
```

And In `bestsellers.blade.php` , i have

```
<input type="text" id="sku" placeholder="Search the sku..." name="sku">
<input type="hidden" id="search_sku" name="search_sku" value="">

<button type="button" id="searchSubmit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button><div class="spin-area" id="spin-area">
 <thead>
       <tr class="odd gradeX"> 
        <th>Sku</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Items Ordered</th>
      <th>Total</th>

        </thead>

  @foreach ($orders as $item )

   <tr class="odd gradeX"> 
    <td><a href="{{ URL::action('SalesFlatOrderItemsController@performance', $item->sku) }}">{{ $item->sku  }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ round( $item->qty_ordered,2) }}</td>
    <td>{{ round( $item->row_total,2) }}</td>
  </tr>
 @endforeach
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is for the input sku should be entered and ajax should help to get the information of sku on the same page. So ajax is as below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#searchSubmit').on('click',function(){
      var data ="sku="+$('#sku').val();

      $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        data:data,
        url:"/bestsellers",
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(data){
          alert('success');
        }

      })
    });
  });

</script>
```

Can somebody let me know what is going wrong with my code, Before this i have used traditional way of post and get request, it works, but not ajax call.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: what is the response you are getting in network?

Comment: if i use url:"/bestsellers", then i am getting page not found error, and when i use url:"bestsellers", i am not getting any error, in network, no errors are shown, how to debug this now

Comment: what about response?

Comment: after clicking the on the button, no events are fired,

Comment: what can be the alternative sir?

Comment: u mean the click event is not firing or the ajax?

Comment: yes, the click event is not working ,

Comment: are you sure that `$('#searchSubmit')` is present in the DOM when you initialize the click event?

Comment: And how can we do that?? I mean how can we make sure that it is present, I mean i have posted the whole code, where i am going wrong

Comment: the html which you have posted is the response which you expect right? what about the html which is already present in the page before ajax request?

Comment: ok , ill edit the blade template code

Comment: i have added the table in the template as you can see

Comment: i think now you can judge it more clearly, where am i going wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).on('click','#searchSubmit',function(){
    var data ="sku="+$('#sku').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        data:data,
        url:"{{URL::to('/bestsellers')}}",
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(data){
            alert('success');
            // data variable will have the data returned by the server. use it to show the response
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: tried this one, it give me 404 error page not found. my actual should be  url:localhost/laravel/public/bestsellers?sku=SDFGD

Comment: but i got localhost/bestseller?sku=SDFGD. thats y uts showing page not found

Comment: in the network i saw the preview, its working over there, but i not getting rendered on the page. and the url is also good. But cnt be rendered on the page

Comment: if you want to render it somewhere then you have to do it. as per your code it will just do an alert saying `'success'`

Comment: Can you just give me the basic idea of how will i render the table on the same page?

Comment: `$('#placeholder').html(data)` will do

Comment: so alert('success'); should be replace by this $('#placehoder').html(data); right? I tried it, but did not work